# Why the service of grpc is undefined when i set configuration for kafka?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs, grpc-node, kafkajs

i'm trying to implement microservices with grpc and kafka but when i add both options in main.ts the client of grpc doesn't load on "onModuleInit" method
this is my main.ts:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.GRPC,
    options:{
      url: '0.0.0.0.:50053',
      package: protobufPackage,
      protoPath: join('./order.proto',)
    },
  });

  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options:{
      client: {
        brokers: ['localhost:29092'],
      },
      consumer: {
        groupId: 'orders-consumer',
      },
    },
  });

  await app.startAllMicroservices();
}
```

and my client in the provider:

```
public onModuleInit(): void {
  this.service = this.clientService<ProductService>(PRODUCT_SERVICE_NAME);
}
```

At this point this.service is undefined only when set kafka configuration, i don't know if I'm missing something or did I misconfigure?

Any suggestion would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `await app.init()` after `app.startAllMicroservices()`